# How to install this magento module

Tags: magento, module, pear

I have purchased this premium plugin for my shopping cart and i m bit confuse how to install it

the instruction here for the module told me to follow these steps at
[http://guides.tinybrick.com/magento/giftcardsuite]

but i m unable to determine how to access command line and install the pear thing

can any one help me?

Comment: Not without knowing much more about the environment you are running Magento in. Server software, OS, whether it's your server or a hosted package....

Answer (score 0):

You can just untar the tar.gz file you received and drop the contents (via ftp or the like) into your root folder of magento. As the site says make sure you do this in a test env not a live one.

Edit: Sorry, not quite true as that is a pear back. TinyBrick have a manual install section check it out. http://guides.tinybrick.com/magento/giftcardsuite-manual-install